# Pass variable into view automatically using middleware

Tags: node.js, express

Searching for a way to automatically pass in a value to a view using express on every request.

I'm using this middleware in my startup script, which basically gets an array of stylesheets which I output in the view.

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    req.styles = helper.getStylesForPage(req.originalUrl);
    next();
});
```

I can then use it when rendering the page:

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    res.render('index', {
        styles: req.styles
    });
});
```

What I'm looking for is a way for this value to automatically be put into this object that's passed into the view, possibly in the middleware function so I don't have to manually do it in every route.

Comment: Aren't you already doing it? _"to automatically be put into this object that's passed into the view, possibly in the middleware function so I don't have to manually do it in every route."_, the first code snippet seems to do that.

Comment: @diegoaguilar well, it's being put into the `req` object, I mean automatically put it in the object that's passed into the view in the second code sample.

Comment: @diegoaguilar yes.

Comment: Is it the same view for all of your routes?

Comment: No it's not... I actually figured it out. See my answer if you're interested.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I figured it out, it turns out I can use `res.locals`. I just switched my middleware function to:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.locals.styles = helper.getStylesForPage(req.originalUrl);
    next();
});
```

As a sidenote, if you aren't aware what `res.locals` is, this object is exposed in your view, and is essentially doing the same thing as this:

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    res.render('index', {
        styles: helper.getStylesForPage(req.originalUrl)
    });
});
```

The only difference is that it's in a re-usable middleware function, so I don't have to put it on every route now.

Comment: Can you use a global `res.locals` at Jade? :o

Comment: It appears to be working :D. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24072444/1426177), it helped me understand.

Comment: Awesome! :) I didnt even know that ;)

Comment: Yep, this particular example was using ejs, so it doesn't matter what view engine you're using either.

Comment: I suggest u to update your own answer, give more details on how u use `locals` at Jade. And provide a link to the other question/asnwer