# How to send variable whin rendering every view using node.js and express.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, authentication

I’m using express.js and i make my own authentication and i need to send an auth variable to every view using `res.render(‘view’)`.
I know about `res.render(‘view’,variable)`,but i need to send this variable whin every views is rendering new or old in other words i need this variable to be sent with every view render function without sending it as a parameter in `res.render(‘view’,parameter)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pass variable into view automatically using middleware](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36170692/pass-variable-into-view-automatically-using-middleware)

Comment: not working cause res.locals also need to be declared with every res.render, I want to make the variable sent automatically with all res.render